# Why isn't the Facebook JavaScript SDK setting cookies?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies

I'm having a problem where the Facebook JavaScript SDK isn't setting cookies on some machines, so my backend validation fails when trying to verify the cookie using my app's secret value.

I've got a [demo app](http://github.com/jcoglan/fb-connect-cookies); the important files are:

- [app.rb](http://github.com/jcoglan/fb-connect-cookies/blob/master/app.rb)
- [demo.js](http://github.com/jcoglan/fb-connect-cookies/blob/master/public/demo.js)

The client uses the Facebook JavaScript API to log the user in and get their details, then posts these to my server. The server sends back the `fbs_APPID` which the client then displays. On some Windows machines (in all browsers) the server doesn't get the cookie it's expected. What's stopping Facebook from setting the cookie, and how do I go about fixing it?

The demo app is in Sinatra but our production app where we found the bug is Rails, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

take a lookt at the initialization code for JS:

```
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
```

Did you enable the cookie one in order to get cookie support? Make sure also that you don't have cookies disabled in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie option sadly isn't that reliable ... personally i prefer to get a signed request of the javascript sdk , send this to the backend as a post var and then decode this signed request there to validate the call...

This way it will also work in safari :)

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is going on, but I think it is a Facebook issue, not an issue with your app. Same thing was happening to me and then it "magically" started working.

See [Why wouldn't the Facebook JavaScript authentication work on a specific computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130708/why-wouldnt-facebook-javascript-authentication-work-on-a-specific-computer)

I'm guessing it has something to do with Facebook caching on a CDN.